# Selenium: Get text in an element with child containing a specific class

Tags: python, selenium

My html page looks like this:

```
<div class="some class">
<p>
   <i class="class1"></i>
   Some Text
</p>
<p>
   <i class="class2"></i>
   Some Text
</p>
.  .  .
.  .  .
.  .  .
</div
```

I want to get Some text. Currently I am trying:

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='some class']")
text = elem.find_element_by_xpath("//p/i[@class='class1']").text
```

But it returns an empty string. I cant understand why. I am new to selenium. Please help.

Comment: Your i tags have no inner text. The text "Some Text" belongs to your p tags. But you should be able to get the parent element by xpath "..".

Comment: @A.Hamza There are two **Some Text** within the HTML, which one are you looking to extract?

Answer (score 1):

You use xpath below:

```
# Find "i" element with "class1" css class and get first parent "p" element
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//i[@class='class1']/ancestor::p[1]")
# Same as previous with added "div"
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='some class']//i[@class='class1']/ancestor::p[1]")

# Find "p" element with child "i" element with "class1" css class
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//p[./i[@class='class1']]")
# Same as previous with added "div"
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='some class']//p[./i[@class='class1']]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is grabbing the element `i` that has attribute `class="class1"`. `i` has no text, which is why it's an empty string, so to fix that:

```py
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='some class']")

# Now let's find the i element you want
i_elem = elem.find_element_by_xpath("//i[@class='class1']")

# Now find the parent of that i_elem, which is p
p_elem = [p for p in i_elem.iterancestors() if p.tag=='p'][0]

txt = p_elem.text
```

Comment: I get it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use execute_script

```
xPath = "//div[@class='some class']"
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xPath)
        b1Text = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].childNodes[2].textContent", element);
        print(b1Text)
except:
       print()
```

try changing the value inside `childNodes[N]` for example childNodes[2], childNodes[1]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `class1` and `class2` are different, you can use this css selector

`div.some class > p:nth-child(1)` to get the text inside it. Since the text is inside the `<p>` para tag, you can get the text from the first `<p>` tag.

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div.some class > p:nth-child(1)")
text = elem.text
```

This should get you the text inside the element.